# fopen() returns inavlid argument when writing on SD card?

Tags: c, linux, file, fopen

I'm trying to write a file on SD card if it's inserted into the kit. Otherwise, the file should be written to the current directory of the project.

I can write the file in the project's directory without any problems.
However, when I try to write it on the inserted SD card, it returns `Invalide argument`!

```
FILE* open_file(void)
{
    char filename[40];
    struct tm *timenow;
    time_t now = time(NULL);

    if(card_inserted())
    {
        // Write to a file in the SD card
        if(!card_mounted())
        {
            system("mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/sdcard/");
        }

        // Change directory from the project's dir to the SD card dir
        chdir("/media/sdcard/");
    }

    timenow = gmtime(&now);

    strftime(filename, sizeof(filename), "logs/data_%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.txt", timenow);

    // Open a file to save the received data in (appending mode)
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "w"); 
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error opening file!\n");
        abort();
    }

    return f;
}
```

I tried changing the `:`s into `-`s in the file name. This caused the error to change to `Input/output error`.

I also tried not to use `chdir()`. Instead, to directly do the following:

```
strftime(filename, sizeof(filename), "/media/sdcard/logs/data_%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.txt", timenow);
```

This didn't solve the problem -> `Invalid argument`.

I'm sure that the SD card is mounted to `/media/sdcard/` and I can create a file into it using the terminal without any problem.

What can cause this error and how to solve it?

**UPDATE**

I made sure that the SD card is correctly mounted before running the program. This didn't solve the problem.

Besides, when I try to write the file into SD card with a normal name, and not the current data and time, it works without any problems!!

Following is my updated code:

```
FILE* open_file(void)
{
    struct tm *timenow;
    time_t now = time(NULL);

    if(card_inserted() &&  write_to_card)
    {
        char *filename;
        filename = "/media/sdcard/logs/data.txt";

        FILE *f = fopen(filename, "w"); 
        if (f == NULL)
            pabort("Error opening file!\n");

        return f;
    }
    else
    {
        char filename[40];
        timenow = gmtime(&now);
        strftime(filename, sizeof(filename), "logs/data_%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.txt", timenow);

        FILE *f = fopen(filename, "w"); 
        if (f == NULL)
            pabort("Error opening file!\n");

        return f;
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem might be how you try to mount the drive

Comment: It's in the posted code: `system("mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/sdcard/");`. Is it not a good way?

Comment: That mounting call looks like a *huge* race condition, I really don't think you can assume that once `system()` returns, the file system has been fully mounted. That'd be my first thing to investigate.

Comment: Try mount from sys/mount.h?

Comment: Do you have logs subdirectory on your card?

Comment: yes I do, and I can write into it when I use a normal name as `data.txt`

Comment: Does your filesystem on SD card allow for : in name? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations)

Comment: No it doesn't. I just checked. But it allows for `-`s.
I tried replacing them with dashes and the error changed to `Input/output error`.

Comment: If you have a true FAT (not exfat or similar) length of filename is also limited.

Comment: Thanks for all of your replies. Before posting the question, I tried replacing `:`s with `-`s but it didn't work. Now, I tried it again and it worked. It turned out that what changed is that I mounted the SD card in terminal before running the program. However, when I let the program to mount it itself, it doesn't work. 
You were right @SaeidYazdani

Comment: In passing - you really ought to check the return value from `system()`, or you might find yourself writing to the wrong filesystem.

Comment: Off-topic, but using `chdir()` in a function is a really bad practice because it affects the state of the entire program.  Code that expects the current directory to be some value will be wrong (although even that's a bad practice, too).  Changing the current working directory can break things, and in a multithreaded process it can introduce race conditions.  Robust code will do exactly the same thing no matter what the current working directory happens to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SD card is probably using a FAT/NTFS file system and filenames in a FAT/NTFS file system cannot contain the `:` character (and a few others).

If you replace the `:` in the format string by `-`, then it should work also on the SD card.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. But this is not the complete answer. This solves only one problem. The other problem is mounting the SD card in the code as pointed out by  @Saeid Yazdani.
Could you please complete your answer?

Comment: @SalahuddinAshraf that's another unrelated question. I suggest you ask another question addressing this specific issue.

Comment: `EINVAL` does seem to be what the FAT filesystem reports for illegal filenames, though `open(2)` doesn't specifically mention that as one of the possible causes of `EINVAL` (probably because normal POSIX filesystems don't prohibit anything).  It seems a reasonable thing to add to that man page, for anybody else experiencing this.